# How to properly serialize a table with multiple foreign keys to same table

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an API for a quiz. However, the table data is not being serialized properly. the field incorrect_answers_ar is sending ascending numbers instead of actual data. all other fields work fine

the serializers is working partially. I'm running django 1.11

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField("Question",max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    question_ar = models.CharField("Question arabic",max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    correct_answer = models.CharField("Correct Answer",max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    correct_answer_ar = models.CharField("Correct Answer arabic",max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.question)

class Incorrect(models.Model):
    incorrect_answers = models.CharField("Incorrect Answer",max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    incorrect_answers_ar = models.CharField("Incorrect Answer arabic",max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,related_name='incorrect_answers', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    question_ar = models.ForeignKey(Question,related_name='incorrect_answers_ar', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.incorrect_answers)
```

admin.py

```
class IncorrectInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Incorrect
    fk_name = "question"

    class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        IncorrectInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import Question,Incorrect


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    incorrect_answers = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question','question_ar', 'correct_answer','correct_answer_ar','incorrect_answers_ar','incorrect_answers')
```

views.py

```
class ListQuestionsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```

this is what I'm getting now

```
[
{
    "question": "how old are you",
    "question_ar": "old arabic",
    "correct_answer": "21",
    "correct_answer_ar": "21 ar",
    "incorrect_answers_ar": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "incorrect_answers": [
        "22",
        "23",
        "24"
    ]
},
{
    "question": "my mobile?",
    "question_ar": "my mobile arabic?",
    "correct_answer": "asus",
    "correct_answer_ar": "asus arabic",
    "incorrect_answers_ar": [
        4,
        5,
        6
    ],
    "incorrect_answers": [
        "redmi",
        "samsung",
        "lg"
    ]
},
{
    "question": "My bike",
    "question_ar": "my bike arabic?",
    "correct_answer": "gixxer",
    "correct_answer_ar": "gixxer arabic",
    "incorrect_answers_ar": [
        7,
        8,
        9
    ],
    "incorrect_answers": [
        "hornet",
        "fz",
        "apache"
    ]
},
{
    "question": "What the hell?",
    "question_ar": "What the hell? arabic",
    "correct_answer": "shit",
    "correct_answer_ar": "shit arabic",
    "incorrect_answers_ar": [
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13
    ],
    "incorrect_answers": [
        "good",
        "bad",
        "okay",
        "great"
    ]
}
]
```

as you can see, the incorrect_answers_ar is throwing numbers instead of real values. any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Those are ids of __Incorrect__ instances related to your question. What do you want to display there instead?

Comment: thier textual values of course, like the other field incorrect_answers showing different text values.

Comment: just added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not define a field explicitly in the serializer, related fields will be serialized with their ids. Like you did for **incorrect_answers**, you also need to define **incorrect_answers_ar** explicitly in the serializer, to use string values. Like this:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    incorrect_answers = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    incorrect_answers_ar = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question','question_ar', 'correct_answer','correct_answer_ar','incorrect_answers_ar','incorrect_answers')
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed it in plain sight. However, now it is sending same values for both incorrect_answers and incorrect_ansers_ar

Comment: Can you please tell me what should i do?

Comment: I think you should solve this on the serializer level. You can not define your __str__ method to return different values depending on which serializer field it is called from. You can define IncorrectAnswerSerializer and IncorrectAnswerArSerializer , which return incorrect_answers and incorrect_answers _ar respectively, and use these serializers as nested in QuestionSerializer